# media query not overriding default css

Tags: css, media-queries

tried to find a solution but didn't find a similar case!!

in order to prevent adding a class name for each page, i would love t use a generic class name just like bellow:

```
<div id="news">
    <div class="news column">content 1</div>
    <div class="news column">content 2</div>
    ...
</div>

#news .news {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .column {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

the default css are not overridden, and the 2 solution i came up with are:
1- use !important, but i'm not a big fan!
2- use the exact class name as in the original css which is "#news .news"

Do you please have something else in mind that can solve this issue??

Thank a lot in advance

Comment: Well this _is_ a matter of specificity, so besides an ugly `!important`, using a selector of at least the same specificity is your only option here, naturally … But where’s the problem with that anyway? You had your reason for using a selector of a certain specificity in the first place, I suppose – so what rationale could there possibly be to not be using that again for different formatting under a different media query condition?

Comment: Thanks Valentin for your reply.
well, i'm using the selectors in the default css coz i have to :) but i wanted to make things a little more rational by adding some class names that can be used only in the media query css so i don't have to update it everytime i create a new page...
As you say, i think it's my only option to use the same specificity... :)

Comment: I have replied to your comment

Comment: No problem, can you please accept this answer if you think I have helped you :), it is the tick right under the arrows. I would really appreciate this :)

Comment: Check this image: http://imgur.com/D2vyvxC DO you see it? inside the red square?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see it before, i'm not very used to stackoverflow... :)
Thanks again for your celerity ;)

Comment: Hi again :)
I have please one question out of topic if you don't mind :)
I'd like to use something like apple site filter: http://store.apple.com/us/mac/mac-accessories/notebook-cases#!
when you click on "Filter", a column in the right appears and the thumbnails move with animation. how is that accomplished??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS an `#ID` is more important than a `class`. Therefore here your class rules will not override the ID ones even though you declare them after.
You can fix your whole problem just by taking note of that.
This is a very important thing in CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #news .column {
        float: none;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that your removed "only" from the media query, is that important??
Also, is the "float: none" important? in other words, should i cancel what has been declared in the default CSS??

Comment: the `only` should not matter. It is just that I do not use it when I use media queries. float: none is not really important, it is juste for total pureness, since you have a full-width element, conceptually it should not float. The important thing here is to override the width: 50%. You almost got it the first time, but the ID was killing the redeclaration as it is more important than a class. By leveling both rules to catch an ID now it works. I hope I made myself clear enough, if not tell me I will help you :)

Comment: You were very clear dear Valentin, and thanks so much for your time and help ;)
Cheers

Comment: No problem, can you please accept this answer if you think I have helped you :), it is the tick right under the arrows. I would really appreciate this :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't see any tick or arrows... :/